# ios Calling is not available

Tags: ios, ipad, call, ipod

How do I know that I can not call from the device? For example for e-mail: `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]`
Anything for calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+123456"]]) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used for calling :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12125551212"]];
```

Please refer this link for more:

[iPhoneURLScheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)